# Android StudioでのCmakeの書き方について

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake

Android StudioにてCmakeを用いてCのソースコードを導入したいのですが、Runをすると下記のエラーが出てしまいます。
ライブラリとしてJava/Kotlinから呼びたいのはmain.cppです。
初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、よろしければご教授いただきたく。
環境:

- OS: Windows10
- Android Studio: Chipmunk 2021.2.1. Patch 1

ファイル構成

- main.cpp
- a.cpp
- a.h

エラー内容:

```
C/C++: ../../../../src/main/cpp/main.cpp:16: error: undefined reference to 'a()'
```

main.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "a.h"

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_clibtest_MainActivity_main(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    a();
}
```

a.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void
a(){
}
```

a.h

```
#ifndef CLIBTEST_A_H
#define CLIBTEST_A_H


extern void a();

#endif //CLIBTEST_A_H
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)    

add_library(a SHARED src/main/cpp/a.cpp)
add_library(main SHARED src/main/cpp/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        main
        a
        android
        log)


include_directories(src/main/cpp/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C/C++関数`a`をJava/Kotlin層に直接公開したいのでなければ、`extern "C"`や`JNIEXPORT`は不要です。

a.cpp

```cpp
#include <a.h>
void a(){
  //(実装)
}
```

`add_library`で構成する共有ライブラリ（≒Java/Kotlin層からロードする実体）は1つで十分なはずです。同共有ライブラリを構成するソースコード群は第3引数以降に全て記述します。

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(main SHARED
  src/main/cpp/main.cpp
  src/main/cpp/a.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
        main
        android
        log)
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、無事にコンパイルすることができました！

Comment: 机上確認だけで回答したので動作確認OKで安心しました :D